# Exporting Oracle View into XML using XSD

Tags: oracle, xsd, oracle11gr2, xmltype

Is it possible to export the data returned from an Oracle View to an XML using an XSD? If so, how do you go about doing so? I have looked through Oracle's XMLType documentation and haven't found anything that seems to fit my particular situation.

Comment: Do you mean the DDL used to create the view? e.g. CREATE VIEW foo or the data returned by a view?

Comment: Hi, I mean the data returned by a view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure about what exactly you need. You may either try

```
select xmltype(cursor(
    select *
    from your_view_vw
)) as view_data_in_xml$ from dual;
```

or write your view to directly construct your XML data via [the XML functions](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions002.htm#SQLRF51186)

or annotate your XSD, register it in Oracle DB as XML-Schema (plus have the Oracle pre-create the object/collection types), then fill in your view's data into the pre-created object/collections, then cast it via the [xmltype.createXML() constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e40758/t_xml.htm#i1009657) with your XSD's name as the `schema` parameter.